# How to create a custom animation on Android Canvas

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I'm working on a project that using custom views created with Android Canvas. And I'm stuck in the next part: How to create custom animations for elements on Android Canvas (the idea), where I cannot use the already-supported-animations. Any idea or example is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to hold some state variables in your `View`. Then you can use `ValueAnimator` or `ObjectAnimator`. Former will trigger `ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener` where you can modify view state in proper way and then `invalidate()`, which trigger redrawing. Latter will update view state via `setSmth()` methods, that you should implement on your view. At the end of these setters you should call `invalidate()` too. And in your `onDraw()` you need to draw proper things depending on actual values of state variables

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.